# Why I'm getting “EXC_BAD_ACCESS” upon trying to release?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management

Would you please have a look at me code:

```
(void)loadContactsFromAddressBook {
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
CFIndex count = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook);
ABRecordRef person;

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    person = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(allPeople, i);
    CFStringRef cfStr = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
    NSString* firstName = (NSString*) cfStr;
    [contacts addObject:firstName]; 
    CFRelease(cfStr);
}

CFRelease(addressBook);
CFRelease(allPeople);
}
```

I tried to CFRelease(person)  after the for block but the application crashes with “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.  If I remove CFRelease(person), the application works.

Comment: Generally only call release if you've `alloc`'d, `init`'d or `copy`'d

Comment: AFAIK, we should also release Core Foundation objects, I'm releasing addressBook and allPeople and the application is working.

Comment: That's because the method names have `create` or `copy` in the names.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You didn't create the person, you only referenced it. *Insert child support joke here.*

Comment: Can I say that methods names in any Apple Core framework tell us wether we have to release or not? For example methods with names contain copy or create mean that we have to release?